# Is Re-indexing possible from admin in mangeto2, if yes, please explain how

Tags: magento2

I have no ssh access, so I want re-indexing from my admin panel in magento 2. Is this possible to re-index data from admin panel in Magento 2?

Comment: you have to create custom script for that to reindexing

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can use a trick to achieve to run indexing from admin panel itself.

Setup the cron job to run command indexer:reindex to run  every 15 min in the cpanel.

**sample:**

```
0,15,30,45  * * * /usr/local/php70/bin/php-cli /home/projectroot/public_html/bin/magento indexer:reindex >> /home/projectroot/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

Then in admin panel under index management set indexing as **"Update on Save"**

And when you need to run the indexing simply change it to **"Update by schedule"** ( As this will allow the cron to run index process)
then simply wait a while that the cron runs and again change it to "Update  on save" so that next cron is not run).

alternatively you can set up a cron to run the command

```
3,18,33,48  * * * /usr/local/php70/bin/php-cli /home/projectroot/public_html/bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime >> /home/projectroot/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

so when in the admin panel if update by schedule is set these two crons will run exactly once and the indexing will again be set to update on save.

Answer (score 0):

Magento have decided to remove this from the Admin. Instead, you will find Magento 2.1 reindexes itself via cron.